# How can i lock a form in position on the desktop?

Tags: winforms, powershell, desktop

I'm trying to make a form in PowerShell that gets locked to a fixed position on the desktop.

Because whenever I press the "Show Desktop" button on the bottom right corner on Win 8.1, the form disappears until I open a different window and close it.

I just want it there like it's a widget, here's a part of the code i'm using:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Add-Type -Assembly System.Drawing
$Image = [System.Drawing.Image]::Fromfile("Panel.png")
$Form = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Form
$Form.BackgroundImage = $Image
$Form.BackgroundImageLayout = "None"
$Form.Text = "Reboot Server"
$Form.Width = 517
$Form.Height = 134
$Form.ControlBox = $False
$Form.StartPosition = 'Manual'
$Form.Location = "1390, 300"
$Form.FormBorderStyle = 'None'
$Form.BackColor = "#000000"
$Form.MaximizeBox = $False
$Form.MinimizeBox = $False
$Form.Icon = "icon.ico"
$Form.Image = [System.Drawing.Image]::Fromfile("Panel.png")
$Form.ShowInTaskbar = $False
$Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Tahoma",10,    [System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Bold)
$Form.Font = $Font
$Label = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$Label.Text = ""
$Label.AutoSize = $True
$Form.Controls.Add($Label)

'       Button 1 - Reboot Server'

$Button1 = new-object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$Button1.Location = new-object System.Drawing.Size(234,51)
$Button1.Size = new-object System.Drawing.Size(77,55)
$Button1.AutoSize = $True
$Button1.Add_Click({start-process "Reboot.lnk"})
$Button1.FlatStyle = [System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle]::Flat
$Button1.FlatAppearance.BorderSize=0
$Button1.BackColor = "Transparent"
$Button1.ForeColor = "Transparent"
$Button1.FlatAppearance.MouseDownBackColor = "Transparent"
$Button1.FlatAppearance.MouseOverBackColor = "Transparent"
$Button1.FlatAppearance.BorderColor = "#252525"
$Form.Controls.Add($Button1)
'----------------------------------------
$Form.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
Exit 0
```

Comment: The purpose of "Show Desktop" is to forcibly hide all application windows. Always-visible desktop gadgets (widgets) were [deprecated in Windows 8](https://www.howtogeek.com/277161/how-to-add-gadgets-back-to-windows-8-and-10-and-why-you-probably-shouldnt/), and Microsoft now seemingly recommends [live tiles](https://www.howtogeek.com/197836/8-ways-to-customize-the-windows-10-start-menu/), but they must be accessed via the Start Menu.

Comment: sorry i was working on something involving VB.NET, my mind was confused.

yeah i understand the point of that but actually i do have other widgets that will always stay on the desktop no matter what, so i'm trying to do the same on my script.

Comment: Did you try `$form.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual; $form.location = new point(1390,300)`

Comment: Otherwise maybe try `$form.left = 1390; $form.top = 300` or try `$form.location.x = 1390; $form.location.y = 300`

Comment: @RobertCotterman Just tried them, no luck.

Answer (score 0):

For gadget style positions try to use a little snippet that I have made:

```
$Poistion = 'RightBottom'
$Coordinates = switch ($Poistion)
{
    'LeftTop' { 0, 0 }
    'LeftBottom'  { 0, $([System.Windows.Forms.Screen]::PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Bottom - $Form.Height) }
    'RightTop' { $([System.Windows.Forms.Screen]::PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width - $Form.Width), 0 }
    'RightBottom' { $([System.Windows.Forms.Screen]::PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width - $Form.Width), $([System.Windows.Forms.Screen]::PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Bottom - $Form.Height) }
}
$Form.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point($Coordinates)
```

To keep your form up at the time when you activate "Show Desktop" set `TopMost` property to `$True` and `MinimizeBox` property to `$False`. Like so:

```
$Form.TopMost = $True
$Form.MinimizeBox = $False
```

When you click on `Show Desktop` or use its hotkey (`Win+D`) windows tries to send `Minimize All` command to running applications. After minimizing all the windows that can be minimized, it then takes the desktop and "raises" it to the top of the window stack so that no other windows cover it.

You could also try to use sizing events. Like so:

```
$Form_Resize={
    $Form.WindowState = 'Normal'
}
$Form.add_Resize($Form_Resize)
```

Comment: @PeeItchPee, I have edited my answer. Try to set `$Form.MinimizeBox = $False` as well.

Comment: I just tried it, it doesn't minimize or hide when i click "Show Desktop" but the form stays on top of all windows all the time, i only want it to be always showing on the desktop.

I really appreciate you trying to help :)

Comment: @PeeItchPee, what do you mean by "i only want it to be always showing on the desktop"? When you use Show Desktop does it get hidden?

Comment: Yeah that's what i mean, i have several other widgets on desktop, when i click on "Show Desktop" i can see all widgets except my form.

Comment: @PeeItchPee, thats wierd. You could try to use sizing events and force form to set to normal state. `$Form_Resize={
    $Form.WindowState = 'Normal'
}
$Form.add_Resize($Form_Resize)`